# Найти минимум среди сумм элементов диагоналей, параллельных главной диагонали

Tags: pascal, матрицы, pascalabc.net

Есть динамический массив

```
var a: array[,] of integer;
```

Вот так я задою его размерность

```
write('Задайте размерность матрицы: ');

read(n);

SetLength(a, n, n);
```

Дальше заполняю

```
writeln('Задайте элементы матрицы: ');

for i := 0 to n - 1 do
  for k := 0 to n - 1 do
  begin
    write('a[', i, ' ', k, '] = ');
    read(a[i, k]);
    a[i, k] := a[i, k];
  end;
```

Как мне "Найти минимум среди сумм элементов диагоналей, параллельных главной диагонали?" были примеры с обычными двумерными массивами где индекс начинается с 1-ы, пытался поправить под себя везде n-1 ставил, но что-то не помогло.

Answer (score 1):

```
begin
  var n := ReadInteger('n =');
  var a := MatrRandom(n, n, -99, 99);
  a.Println(5);
  var smin := MaxInt;
  // верхняя треугольноая матрица
  for var k := 1 to n - 2 do
  begin
    var s := 0;
    for var i := 0 to n - 1 - k do
      s += a[i, i + k];
    if s < smin then smin := s
  end;
  // нижняя треугольная матрица
  for var k := 1 to n - 2 do
  begin
    var s := 0;
    for var i := k to n - 1 do
      s += a[i, i - k];
    if s < smin then smin := s
  end;
  smin.Print
end.
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]